# Expanding a scroll view with a Draggable UI Object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to create a draggable and expandable UI in Unity.

I have been able to create a draggable button with this code.

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class UIDragableScript : MonoBehaviour {

 //Threshold
 float OffsetX;
 float OffsetY;

 public void BeginDrag()
 {
    OffsetX = transform.position.x - Input.mousePosition.x;
    OffsetY = transform.position.y - Input.mousePosition.y;
 }

 public void OnDrag()
 {
    transform.position = new Vector3(OffsetX + Input.mousePosition.x,
                                     OffsetY + Input.mousePosition.y);
 }
}
```

I would like to create an expandable UI that can expand when the button is dragged across the scrollView UI.

Currently the structure is like this:

[image]

What I would like to have is this:

[image]

Comment: `UI that can expand` can you specify that closer? Than in your code I don't see anything related to this behaviour so far so ... where is exactly is your coding related question (Please refer to [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic))?

Comment: @derHugo : I have attached the picture to explain the UI behaviour that i would like to achieve. for example when the Button is dragged to the right I would like the "scroll View" to expland to the right as well..

I wonder if it is possible to achieve that behaviour without code.. ? just with the unity component. (e.g. Grid Layout Group or Content Size Fitter)